# Class that implements ArrayAccess throws Fatal Error if not defined first

Tags: php, oop

I have the following file:

```
<?php

$inc = new includer;

?>

<!-- ... snip lots of HTML ... -->

<?php

class includer {

    protected $obj;

    public function __construct() {
        $this->obj = new obj;
    }

}

// obj taken from PHP ArrayAccess page as example, contents not important
class obj implements ArrayAccess {
    private $container = array();

    public function __construct() {
        $this->container = array(
            "one"   => 1,
            "two"   => 2,
            "three" => 3,
        );
    }

    public function offsetSet($offset, $value) {
        if (is_null($offset)) {
            $this->container[] = $value;
        } else {
            $this->container[$offset] = $value;
        }
    }

    public function offsetExists($offset) {
        return isset($this->container[$offset]);
    }

    public function offsetUnset($offset) {
        unset($this->container[$offset]);
    }

    public function offsetGet($offset) {
        return isset($this->container[$offset]) ? $this->container[$offset] : null;
    }
}
```

When the instantiation of the `includer` class is at the bottom of the file (with the class definitions at the top of the file), everything works great. With the class instantiation at the top of the file as shown, I get the following error:

```
Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Class 'obj' not found in \test\classes.php on line 16
```

If I remove the `implements ArrayAccess` portion from the `obj` class, everything works fine regardless of where `includer` is instantiated.

The file is a single page PHP/HTML/JS file with all my PHP classes and function definitions at the bottom. So I'd really like to avoid putting these classes at the top simply because of the `ArrayAccess` portion. I also don't require any lecture about spaghetti code and the like. It was a conscious decision to write it this way.

I also tried with and without the function call parens (`$inc = new includer;` vs `$inc = new includer();`), and neither made any difference on either of the class instantiation calls.

I also tried with and without namespaces (`\ArrayAccess` vs `ArrayAccess`), also no luck.

What can I do to stop PHP from being whiny about this one class not being defined before it's instantiated? Other classes (that don't implement ArrayAccess) get instantiated just fine with the class definition at the bottom of the file.

Comment: is that possible to create an object for var?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The same behavior happens with any interface, so not specific to `ArrayAccess`.

In the PHP documentation [Objects and Classes -> The Basics](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.basic.php), there is a very terse hint (I put it in bold) in the **new** section:

> To create an instance of a class, the new keyword must be used.
>   An object will always be created unless the object has a constructor
>   defined that throws an exception on error. Classes should be defined
>   before instantiation **(and in some cases this is a requirement)**.

It seems a good bet that a class that implements an interface would fall under the category of requiring definition before instantiation.

The inconsistency you found is definitely confusing, but likely you are stuck with definition before instantiation, which is a best practice anyway.

Comment: As much as I hate to mark correct the answer I was dreading, I suppose I have to.  ;)